# Mysterious blank page before \chapter using \chapterlinesformat in spite of openany/oneside (KOMA-script)

Tags: chapters, koma-script, blank-page

Each time I produce a new chapter, I want to have a single page with the chapter title at the center of it.
Following the KOMA-script documentation, and looking online, I've managed to do it by redefining `\chapterlinesformat`.

Here is what I don't understand:

- If I use my code to center some content inside the document, everything works fine
- If I use the same code to rewrite `\chapterlinesformat`, a blank page appears
- So clearly `\chapterlinesformat` do something just before it writes the chapter.

Online searches quickly told me that a blank page before chapter was usually because of odd/even numbered pages or such, and that a quick fix was to use openany/oneside option.
I've tried to look at KOMA-script documentation to understand where this blank page came from, without success.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterheadstartvskip {}{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterheadendvskip {}{}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterlinesformat {mmm}
    {
    \clearpage %need to be removed for no blank page before \chapter, why?
    \topskip0pt
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
    #3
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \clearpage
    }

\begin{document}

\blindtext

% DO NOT PRODUCE BLANK PAGE BEFORE Test
\clearpage
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
Test
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage

\blindtext
%BLANK PAGE before Chapter, why?
\chapter{Chapter}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added a \blindtext before the first centered text and the problem is still the same. Even if I add \null before \clearpage in both cases, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the question. What is exactly bothering you? `\clearpage` does not mean "make a blank page". `\chapter` already issues a `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`), then does some typesetting, and that's why the second `\clearpage` in `\chapterlinesformat` makes another new page, effectively leaving one blank.

Comment: Ok I understand, now, \chapter already issues a \clearpage.

Comment: `\chapter` does many things before it calls `\chapterlinesformat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to redefine `\chapterlinesformat`. You can simple redefine `\chapterheadstartvskip`, `\chapterheadendvskip`, `\raggedchapter` and `\chapterformat` to get

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vfill\clearpage}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vfill
\begin{center}
Test
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage
\blindtext
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

You can redefine `\chapterformat` to change the layout of the chapter number. Simple example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vfill\clearpage}

\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \path(current page text area.center)node[scale=30,lightgray]{\thechapter};%
}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vfill
\begin{center}
Test
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage
\blindtext

\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm also doing fancy things with the chapter number that wasn't relevant to the problems, adding it super-large to the background of the page with a tikzpicture

Comment: You could redefine `\chapterformat`. See the example in my updated answer.

Comment: So when to use `\chapterlinesformat`?

Comment: You can use `\chapterlinesformat` to change the order of number and title or to put them together in a frame. You have to redefine this command if there should be a rule above and/or below of the chapter heading or if you want use `\MakeUppercase` for the chapter heading etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is simply that `\chapter` issues a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`, so since there is already one `\clearpage` at the beginning in the command I created with `\chapterlinesformat`, this creates a blank page when I call `\chapter`

Thanks to campa for the answer.

Comment: note _just_ calling `\clearpage` would not be enough to cause this (two consecutive `\clearpage` do not make a blank page) but the chapter code has already put something (a box or a `\write` for example) on to the page so the `\clearpage` that you add does cause a page that is all white (but not empty according to TeX's internal view) to be shipped out.